# Change translate

Tags: customer, template, magento-1, address

I made several changes on the page `/customer/address/`

In the list

```
name name
company
address 1
address 2
city
contry
phone: 0541
Fax: 00000000009999
VAT: codfiscal332
```

[image]

I used the fields F and VAT for another use.

I need to chande the labels F and VAT.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the customer address templates in *System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Address Templates*:

[image]

This one is the HTML template but you should take a look at the other templates as well, to also change the represantation in emails, PDFs etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the address customer template. In your case I think you should change the labels in this phtml file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml` or you should check if your themes has overwritten it.

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau: why your downvote?